# Not able to make calls to native android code in Unity3D

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

Not able to call native code in Unity

I'm quite at wits end, and thats saying something. It seems no matter what I do I'm not able to succesfully make a crosscall back to an android class from Unity. My C# class

```
 AndroidJavaClass soundActivityJavaClass;
     AndroidJavaObject soundActivityObject;
     string parse = "";
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         AndroidJNIHelper.debug = true;
         AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
         soundActivityJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.stuff.oro.UnityBridge");
         soundActivityObject = soundActivityJavaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
         parse = soundActivityObject.Call<string>("testBridge");

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {


     }

     void OnGUI()
     {
         if (GUI.Button(new Rect(300, 0, 100, 50), "Get mode..."))
         {
             AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.stuff.oro.UnityBridge");
             AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");

             print(jo.Call<string>("testBridge"));
             Debug.Log(jo.Call<string>("testBridge"));
         }
     }
```

My current android class:

```
 public class UnityBridge extends UnityPlayerActivity{

     public static UnityBridge instance;
     public String testBridge(){
         return "this is a test";
     }
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         UnityBridge.instance = this;
     }

     public UnityBridge getInstance(){
         return instance;
     }

 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I got from not being able to compile, to having

11-30 23:27:53.960: I/Unity(25864): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no static field with name='instance' signature='Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Lcom/stuff/oro/UnityBridge;

11-30 23:27:53.960: I/Unity(25864): at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will ever wonder:

Essentially I was never able to specifically call non-static methods on classes that inherited UnityPlayerActivity. Eventually I just dropped inherreting from it at all (which is possible enough) and if I ever was in a situation where I needed the actual Activity (for context or the like), I called UnityPlayer.currentActivity

Hope this helps someone